# How can I make this controller method less heavy?

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, business-logic

Let's say I have the following controller and contained method. I feel like this controller method (list) is too heavy. How should I split this up? What should be moved to the view layer, and what should be moved to the model layer?

Note: The return format (hash containing :text, :leaf:, id, :cls) contains different fields from what's in the ProjectFile database table, so this makes me question how much of this controller method should actually be moved to the model layer.

```
class ProjectFileController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user

  def list
    @project_id = params[:project_id]
    @folder_id = params[:folder_id]

    current_user = UserSession.find
    @user_id = current_user && current_user.record.id

    node_list = []

    # If no project id was specified, return a list of all projects.
    if @project_id == nil and @folder_id == nil
      # Get a list of projects for the current user.
      projects = Project.find_all_by_user_id(@user_id)

      # Add each project to the node list.
      projects.each do |project|
        node_list << {
          :text => project.name,
          :leaf => false,
          :id => project.id.to_s + '|0',
          :cls => 'project',
          :draggable => false
        }
      end
    else
      # If a project id was specfied, but no file id was also specified, return a
      # list of all top-level folders for the given project.
      if @project_id != nil and @folder_id == nil
        # Look for top-level folders for the project. 
        @folder_id = 0
      end

      directory_list = []
      file_list = []

      known_file_extensions = ['rb', 'erb', 'rhtml', 'php', 'py', 'css', 'html', 'txt', 'js', 'bmp', 'gif', 'h', 'jpg', 'mov', 'mp3', 'pdf', 'png', 'psd', 'svg', 'wav', 'xsl']

      # Get a list of files by project and parent directory.
      project_files = ProjectFile.find_all_by_project_id(@project_id,
                                                         :conditions => "ancestry like '%#{@folder_id}'",
                                                         :order => 'name')

      project_files.each do |project_file|
        file_extension = File.extname(project_file.name).gsub('.', '')

        if known_file_extensions.include? file_extension
          css_class_name = file_extension
        else
          css_class_name = 'unknown'
        end

        # Determine whether this is a file or directory.
        if project_file.is_directory
          directory_list << {
            :text => project_file.name,
            :leaf => false,
            :id => @project_id + '|' + project_file.id.to_s,
            :cls => css_class_name
          }
        else
          file_list << {
            :text => project_file.name,
            :leaf => true,
            :id => @project_id + '|' + project_file.id.to_s,
            :cls => css_class_name
          }
        end
      end

      node_list = directory_list | file_list
    end

    render :json => node_list
  end
end
```

Comment: You could stop putting the business and presentational logic in the controller. That would help a lot.

Comment: @teresko The question is *how*.

Comment: @jeriley Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could put most of that logic in your model `ProjectFile` or whatever is the appropriate model name:

```
ProjectFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def node_list(project_id, folder_id, user_id)
    node_list = []

    # If no project id was specified, return a list of all projects.
    if project_id == nil and folder_id == nil
    # Get a list of projects for the current user.
    projects = Project.find_all_by_user_id(user_id)

      # Add each project to the node list.
      projects.each do |project|
        node_list << {
          :text => project.name,
          :leaf => false,
          :id => project.id.to_s + '|0',
          :cls => 'project',
          :draggable => false
        }
      end
    else
      # If a project id was specfied, but no file id was also specified, return a
      # list of all top-level folders for the given project.
      if project_id != nil and folder_id == nil
        # Look for top-level folders for the project. 
        folder_id = 0
      end

      directory_list = []
      file_list = []

      known_file_extensions = ['rb', 'erb', 'rhtml', 'php', 'py', 'css', 'html', 'txt', 'js', 'bmp', 'gif', 'h', 'jpg', 'mov', 'mp3', 'pdf', 'png', 'psd', 'svg', 'wav', 'xsl']

      # Get a list of files by project and parent directory.
      project_files = ProjectFile.find_all_by_project_id(project_id,
                                                     :conditions => "ancestry like '%#{folder_id}'",
                                                     :order => 'name')

      project_files.each do |project_file|
        file_extension = File.extname(project_file.name).gsub('.', '')

        if known_file_extensions.include? file_extension
          css_class_name = file_extension
        else
          css_class_name = 'unknown'
        end

        # Determine whether this is a file or directory.
        if project_file.is_directory
          directory_list << {
            :text => project_file.name,
            :leaf => false,
            :id => project_id + '|' + project_file.id.to_s,
            :cls => css_class_name
        }
        else
          file_list << {
            :text => project_file.name,
            :leaf => true,
            :id => project_id + '|' + project_file.id.to_s,
            :cls => css_class_name
          }
        end
      end

      node_list = directory_list | file_list
    end
end
```

Then break up `node_list` into more manageable methods. The method I've defined above is long and does multiple things (low cohesion), so breaking it up will help combat those shortcomings.

In your controller you would call this like:

```
class ProjectFileController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user

  def list
    @project_id = params[:project_id]
    @folder_id = params[:folder_id]

    current_user = UserSession.find
    @user_id = current_user && current_user.record.id

    nodes = node_list(@project_id, @folder_id, @user_id)
    render :json => nodes
  end
end
```

Now your controller is much simpler to read and the business logic is extracted. This follows the mantra "skinny controllers, fat models".

Comment: Now, the node_list function returns data in an arbitrary format. Is this proper? Perhaps the node_list function should live in the ProjectFileHelper class instead since the format is closely tied to what the view expects?

Comment: @Chad - the data looks pretty similar. They're both arrays containing hashes right?

Comment: Try breaking the model code up into even smaller pieces by creating small methods that do stuff. Methods that can be tested by unit tests. Often when a method is untestable, because you have to stub the hell out of it, it's a sign that you need to rip out stuff into smaller methods that can be tested in isolation.

Comment: @xinit - just to clarify, I did mention that in my post but it's sandwiched between the code. I didn't want to attempt to break up his code without knowing exactly what each aspect does.

Comment: @McStretch Similar but not the same. Point is, the node_list function does not return a list of ProjectFile models. Is it okay for a method in a model to return an arbitrary hash rather than models of its own type?

Comment: @McStretch that's why you want tests :)

Comment: @Chad - Ah I see what you're getting at now. You could also create a separate model that builds the `node_list`, but don't bother inheriting from `ActiveRecord`. This could still be called in your controller, with your parameters.

Comment: @xinit - Haha yeah I'll leave that as a todo for the OP :P

Comment: @McStretch my comment was actually meant for the OP :) That controller method is way to big..

Answer (score 1):

You should have an Association in your User model like

```
has_many => :projects
```

So you can get an array of the project obejcts with

```
current_user.projects
```

Instead of this:

```
projects = Project.find_all_by_user_id(@user_id)
```

which means you also don't need to retrieve the user_id.

You could also put all the logic for populating the node_list into your User model.  Just put in your model:

```
def node_list(project_id, folder_id=0)
  if @project_id == nil
    list = self.projects.map do |project|
      {
        :text => project.name,
        :leaf => false,
        :id => project.id.to_s + '|0',
        :cls => 'project',
        :draggable => false
      }
    end
  else
    ... # the rest of your code here, etc
  end
  return list
end
```

Notice this can also remove your check if folder_id is nil and set to zero, because the `folder_id=0` in the `def node_list(project_id, folder_id=0)` will do that automatically.

Then your controller would just look like this:

```
def list
  @current_user = UserSession.find
  render :json => @current_user.node_list(params[:project_id], params[:folder_id])
end
```

**Also:**

Since you are just combining the directory_list and file_list anyway, why not just combine that if-else statement into:

```
{
  :text => project_file.name,
  :leaf => project_file.is_directory,
  :id => @project_id + '|' + project_file.id.to_s,
  :cls => css_class_name
}
```

You can always sort the array afterwards, if necessary.

Comment: Since you are getting the @user_id from current_user.record.id, I'm guessing that projects are actually associated with a Records model.  In which case, you can either more all this to the Records model and call it with `@current_user.record.node_list` or you can use a has_many :through association in your User model.  I would probably prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1):

@Chad,

I think you've got good examples of refactoring of your code from people who've posted before me.

You seem capable enough to write ruby code so i'm going to try to answer your question from a "how to refactor" point of view.

- Keep controllers skinny

  - Use before filters where applicable
  - Each controller end point (action) is a method in the controller class and it should have a "singular" responsibility.
  - Your "list" method is supposed to find the relevant data (using a method call to an appropriate model class) and let Rails do the default rendering. You're returning json, so one line for that is fine.
  - Now you need to invoke at the most one and in exceptional cases two methods on a model.
  - I've come up with this adage for me "if action method more than 10 lines long, its wrong".
- Keep models fat

  - Break down your problem into smaller problems.
  - your list method has too many branches of code.
  - perhaps on a high level you may want to break it down into a "semantic" controller type method in your model which does the primary juggling of if then else.
  - other smaller methods do the rest.
  - Model methods should also have a small set of parameters. Too many parameters and it's brittle and no parameters means it's tied to too much state.
  - Method with 1 or 2 parameters is good. You can have a method with 3 parameters of options. Anything more than 3 parameters is ripe for refactoring.
  - Current user object can be passed into the model, there is nothing wrong with that.
  - Or enrich your user model by adding more methods in there. (has_many :projects and then use the methods provided by the associations).
  - I keep the associations documentation handy with me at all times.
  - I keep the enumerables documentation handy with me at all times.
  - Learn what map, select, reject, find do in Enumerables. They are your friends!

Good luck! :)